# Counting Fridays 13th

Tags: algorithm, date

My homework was to make a program which will count all fridays 13th from the interval. You have got 2 dates:

- 6.8.1924
- 1.1.2015

It has to count all fridays 13th from that period. I made it and everything works but here's the problem:

After year 4 000 it counts incorectly. If both or atleast one of those dates is higher than 4 000 my program will output number of fridays 13th higher than it should be. The program works like that:

```
If firstday in month == Sunday then
   countFirday++;
```

It loops all months from the period but there's 28 year cycle which repeats or 400 year cycle which repeats so it's optimalized and quite fast for big numbers.

I even tried it with doomsday algorithm but the result was the same like with my own algorithm.

I'm probably too stupid to get it and ask you for a small hint why it counts wrong after year 4000. I appreciate all your help thanks.

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: Did you take into account "leap year"?

`Leap Year =  (year%400 == 0 || year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) ? true:false;`

Comment: Have you tried without the 28-year-cycle optimization? Does it work without?

Comment: well i tried it with 400 year cycle and without the result and numbers were the same. And i did not forget to put there conditions for leap years  + i put there condition, that year 4 000 is not a leap year. There must be something else i am not aware of.

Comment: Do you know 6.8.1924 which day? Or do you have only two dates?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have year 4000 marked as a leap year? It should be a leap year if:

The year is evenly divisible by 4;
If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

Comment: Yeah it's implemented.

Comment: Can't show the whole code only small parts and not that much we upload it to the school system and the system tests it for all the possible data + if ppl got the same code or similiar they will get penalized hard. So im kind of afraid of that many ppl have not made it and its almost deadline so.

Comment: You said above: 'i put there condition, that year 4 000 is not a leap year'. Year 4000 is a leap year.

Comment: 4 000 year is not a leap year even thought the year is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I have tried to solve this task.

For input

```
06.08.1924
01.01.2015
```

Result will be: `155`.

```
#include<cstdio>

bool isLeapYear(int year){
    return (year%400 == 0 || year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) ? true: false;
}

bool isMonthFebruary(int month){
    return month == 2 ? true : false;
}


int getDaysInMonth(int m, int year){
    if(isMonthFebruary(m)){
        if(isLeapYear(year)) return 29;
        return 28;
    }

    if(m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) return 30;

    return 31;
}


void getNextDay(int &fromDay, int &fromMonth, int &fromYear)
{

    int daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(fromMonth, fromYear);

    if(fromMonth == 12 && fromDay == daysInMonth){
        fromYear ++;
        fromMonth = 1;
        fromDay = 1;
    }else if(fromDay == daysInMonth) {
        fromMonth ++;
        fromDay = 1;
    }else {
    fromDay ++;
    }
}

int main(){

    int fromDay, fromMonth, fromYear;
    int toDay, toMonth, toYear;
    int startDay = 1, startMonth = 1, startYear = 1;
    int days = 1;

    int fridayQty = 0;

    scanf("%02d.%02d.%04d", &fromDay, &fromMonth, &fromYear);
    scanf("%02d.%02d.%04d", &toDay, &toMonth, &toYear);

    while(!(startYear == fromYear && startMonth == fromMonth && startDay == fromDay)){
        getNextDay(startDay, startMonth, startYear);
        days ++;
    }

    while(!(fromYear == toYear && fromMonth == toMonth && fromDay == toDay)){
        if(fromDay == 13 && days%7 == 5) fridayQty ++;
        getNextDay(fromDay, fromMonth, fromYear);
        days ++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", fridayQty);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well i can say that your code does not work even for smaller dates like 1.1.1900 -- 1.1.2015 it should output : 197 ur program gives output : 195 and i did not need the whole code just somebody to try to figure out why it does count incorrectly after year 4000 coz i spent too much time thinking , googling about it and i have found nothing

Comment: Ok, understood. Please try now. I have updated my solution.

Comment: assert ( CountFriday13 ( 2174, 11, 14, 205101914, 10, 25, &cnt ) == 1 && cnt == 351599554LL );
assert ( CountFriday13 ( 2055,  3, 15, 209725592, 11, 12, &cnt ) == 1 && cnt == 359526067LL );
assert ( CountFriday13 ( 2021, 1, 21, 20947, 10, 16, &cnt ) == 1 && cnt == 32440LL );
assert ( CountFriday13 ( 2142, 4,  2, 20286,  1, 11, &cnt ) == 1 && cnt == 31095LL );
if it will work for all those data correctly then you can help me and tell me what u made in ur code to work it for dates above 4000. Thanks.